# How to hide null columns in chart js if they are in a group of data

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have been strugling with this problem for some days. I need to make a barchart that shows the sells on months and with the days of that sells.

This is what I manage to do.

[image]

As you can see there are a lot of blank spaces.
For the above example, I receive this data from java (and sql server), that is use in the chart:

```
[{"datasets":[{"backgroundColor":["rgb(52, 152, 219)","rgb(52, 152, 219)","rgb(52, 152, 219)","rgb(52, 152, 219)"],"borderColor":["rgb(52, 152, 219)","rgb(52, 152, 219)","rgb(52, 152, 219)","rgb(52, 152, 219)"],"stack":1,"data":[411.75,null,null,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"24/12/22"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)"],"borderColor":["rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)"],"stack":1,"data":[null,29534.25,null,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"01/01/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)"],"borderColor":["rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)"],"stack":2,"data":[null,50000,null,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"04/01/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)"],"borderColor":["rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)"],"stack":3,"data":[null,20,null,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"11/01/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)"],"borderColor":["rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)"],"stack":4,"data":[null,50,null,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"12/01/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)"],"borderColor":["rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)"],"stack":5,"data":[null,10,null,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"20/01/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)"],"borderColor":["rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)","rgb(64, 212, 126)"],"stack":6,"data":[null,29852.17,null,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"31/01/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"borderColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"stack":1,"data":[null,null,30,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"03/02/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"borderColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"stack":2,"data":[null,null,50,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"06/02/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"borderColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"stack":3,"data":[null,null,260,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"07/02/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"borderColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"stack":4,"data":[null,null,130,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"08/02/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"borderColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"stack":5,"data":[null,null,102283.5,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"10/02/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"borderColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"stack":6,"data":[null,null,989.89,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"13/02/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"borderColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"stack":7,"data":[null,null,4459.45,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"15/02/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"borderColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"stack":8,"data":[null,null,1044.89,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"16/02/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"borderColor":["rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)","rgb(230, 126, 34)"],"stack":9,"data":[null,null,200,null],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"24/02/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)"],"borderColor":["rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)"],"stack":1,"data":[null,null,null,844.63],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"02/03/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)"],"borderColor":["rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)"],"stack":2,"data":[null,null,null,2530],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"09/03/23"},{"backgroundColor":["rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)"],"borderColor":["rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)","rgb(180, 84, 182)"],"stack":3,"data":[null,null,null,79490.595],"borderWidth":"1","skipNull":true,"label":"10/03/23"}],"labels":["Diciembre de 2022","Enero de 2023","Febrero de 2023","Marzo de 2023"]}]
```

My problem comes with the maner I'm using the column data in order to be able to put the amounts with their corresponding day and in their corresponding month.
For example here:

`"data":[null,null,null,79490.595]`

As you see on the example, I choose to show the data from december 2022 to march 2023, four months, so the way I found to put the amounts on their corresponding month was to send null values on the other months, so for example the 79490.595 can be show on march and not in december with all the other data. The problem here is that it generates blank spaces on the other months. That happens with all the other data.

[image]

So I would like to know if it is a way to show only the data and not the nulls.

I tried to use the **hidden : true;**  , but that deletes all the data and not only the nulls. Then I tried other aproach using in the previous example of data **hidden: [true,true,true,false]** , but of corse, it didn´t work (i tried also generating **hidden: [false,false,false,true]** , if I was confusing the right boolean, but also didn't work).

I Can make modifications on java's code, if you propose something regarding with it.

Also if it helps, here is the part of the script of creation of the chart, if I can add something there:

```
<canvas id="graficaGananciasProductos" style="width: 100px;"\>\</canvas\>

    var grafica = document.getElementById("graficaGananciasProductos");
    
    new Chart(grafica, {
        type: "<%=xTipo%>",
        data: <%=respuesta%>,
        stacked: false,
        options: {
            skipnull: true,
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                        stacked: false
                    }],
                yAxes: [{
                        stacked: false
                    }]
            }
        }
    });
```

- **xTipo** says the chart if it is a vertical bar chart or horizontal
- **respuesta** are the datasets and labels that are generated depending on date intervals. I send the example of the generated data
  for the chart I show in the image.

### Thank you!

Tried using hidden on the dataset, but it hides all the data of the array of columns, so tried to make an array of booleans in hidden, to try to use the hide on the columns I really want to hide,but it didn't work.
I search a lot on google, with a lot of results here on stackoverflow and another webs. I also tried to search only in stackoverflow, but couldn't find something for that especific problem.
I also have to say that I never worked before with Chart js, so I'm a totally newby with it and don't know other thing to try.

- I tried also with things suggested [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2092), but as I don't know
  where to copy and past that code or how to work with the chart jss
  code, I couldn't made it work yet.

Comment: Hi, on march I let this chart as it was with that problem, but again I've been asked to change it, but still I don't know how to solve this problem.

Someone know how to try to solve it? 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for days and days on internet, and don't find an answer, I had to change a bit the way I was doing the chart. I made the dataset to have data for 31 days, and on months that have less days, I put a null value for that days. Still I can't get rid of the blank spaces generated by them, but now they are way less than before.

Maybe due to size of the space where run the snipper it can't be seen, but if you see it on full size it will be clear. There is something that I couldn't show on the snipper, maybe I missed some library, but on the picture it shows two numbers on the bars. The number over the bar is the day, and the one on the middle of the bar are the sales on that day.

Hope that if someone is facing this same problem with months, can find the code/example useful.

```js
var grafica1 = document.getElementById("graficaGananciasProductos_0");

var chart1 = new Chart(grafica1, {
  type: "bar",
  data: {
    "datasets": [{
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [567, 734, 577],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "01"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [620, 854, 686],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "02"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [12, 557, 567],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "03"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [12, 46, 256],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "04"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [567, 345, 644],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "05"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [620, 3445, 456],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "06"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [12, 866, 136],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "07"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [12, 455, 467],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "08"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [567, 356, 577],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "09"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [620, 456, 167],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "10"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [12, 45, 467],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "11"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [12, 3556, 45],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "12"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [567, 356, 257],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "13"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [620, 34, 126],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "14"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [12, 866, 567],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "15"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [12, 554, 456],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "16"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [567, 3445, 755],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "17"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [620, 865, 467],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "18"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [12, 477, 567],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "19"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [12, 64, 755],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "20"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [567, 345, 567],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "21"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [620, 123, 554],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "22"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [784, 456, 567],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "23"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [467, 34, 567],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "24"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [874, 824, 456],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "25"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [678, 245, 5467],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "26"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [12, 67, 354],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "27"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [578, 456, 654],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "28"
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [567, null, 564],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "29",
        "skipNull": true
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [620, null, 741],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "30",
        "skipNull": true
      },
      {
        "backgroundColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "borderColor": ["rgb(64, 212, 126)", "rgb(52, 152, 219)", "rgb(230, 126, 34)"],
        "data": [1234, null, 852],
        "borderWidth": "1",
        "label": "31",
        "skipNull": true
      }
    ],
    "labels": ["Enero de 2023", "Febrero de 2023", "Marzo de 2023"]
  },
  stacked: false,
  options: {
    skipnull: true,
    barPercentage: 1,
    categoryPercentage: 1,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: false,
        barPercentage: 0.7,
        categoryPercentage: 1
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: false
      }]
    },
    animation: {
      "onComplete": function() {
        var chartInstance = this.chart,
          ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

        ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

        this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
          var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
          meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
            var data = dataset.label;
            ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/2.2.0/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <canvas id="graficaGananciasProductos_0"></canvas>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I can't upload images, here it is how it should look with the code I use on the snipper.
https://imgur.com/b27WScN

Thanks